# Using addContextMenuItem in sl4a

Tags: android, python, sl4a

How do you use [addContextMenuItem](http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/wiki/ApiReference#addContextMenuItem) in sl4a?

I'm using the [experimental full-screen UI](http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/wiki/FullScreenUI) to display a list view.  I want to:
1) trap a long-press on an item on the list
2) show a "pop-up" menu of options relating to that item.

The listview part works fine.

I know how I can do 2) once I get an event (simply display an alert and add items) but I can't see what user action actually triggers the event you define, or how to control it.

E.g. what will fire the "Play" event defined below, and how do I control what does?

```
droid.addContextMenuItem("Play", "contextmenu", "test")
```